# docker postgres backup creates an empty file when run as a cron job

Tags: linux, docker, postgresql, cron, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a cronjob that creates db backups every night.

My crontab has the job:
`* * * * * /home/user/scripts/backup.sh` (have it set to go off every min for testing)

In backup.sh, I have:

```
docker exec -it dbContainer pg_dump -U username -d dbName > /home/user/backups/testingBackup.sql
```

The file is always empty:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 Jul 14 08:39 testingBackup.sql
```

However, if I run the file on my own and type the command `/home/user/scripts/backup.sh`,
it is not empty:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 30813 Jul 14 08:45 testingBackup.sql
```

I feel like it makes sense something is off on the permissions, but everything is done from the "user". I haven't done anything from root such as sudo crontab... sudo /home/user/backups/testingBackup.sql, etc.

I am confused as to why in one scenario, the resulting file is empty, and in the other, it is not.

Thanks for any help

Comment: hows about #!/bin/bash in your script? and you may add SHELL=/bin/bash to crontab

Comment: sorry for the extremely late response, got completely sidetracked, but neither of those helped :(

Comment: please show me the current state

Comment: the sql file that is created...
-rw-rw-r--  1 user  user 0 Aug 26 14:14 testingBackup.sql

cron:
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 4 * * * /path/otherjob.sh
* * * * * /path/backup.sh

backup file:
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/docker exec -it dbContainer pg_dump -U postgres  -d db > path/testingBackup.sql

Comment: but if i just run: path/backup.sh, I get: -rw-rw-r--  1 user user 224622 Aug 26 14:18 testingBackup.sql

Answer (score 0):

for the command I have in the sh file:
 `docker exec -it dbContainer pg_dump -U username -d dbName > /home/user/backups/testingBackup.sql`

It is running in interactive mode (-it). If I remove this, everything works (so command is:
 `docker exec dbContainer pg_dump -U username -d dbName > /home/user/backups/testingBackup.sql`